# can't find reason why I can't read from editText

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick, android-edittext

In the code below, when the 'submit' button is pushed, I'm trying to get the values from three editTexts. After I get the String values, I want to convert them to int values and check whether they are in the specified range.

However I am having trouble getting the values from editText. I'm not sure if this is the problem or if there is another even bigger flaw with my code.

When I enter the three editTexts and press the 'submit' button, the app stops with the 'submit' button pressed down. It seems as if it's in some sort of loop - just a guess. So, the toast msg doesn't appear on my screen(Even after I changed my code with what @sunnyday mentioned). The app just seems stalled. It won't even go back to the previous activity.

I am just starting Android and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Java Code:

```
package activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.chloe.myapplication.R;

public class PayActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button submitButton, flip;
    Switch switchButton;
    EditText et_totalPeople, et_payPeople, et_amount;
    TextView tv_payPeople, tv_people;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pay_numofpeople);

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        switchButton = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
        et_totalPeople= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_totalPeople);
        et_payPeople= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_payPeople);
        et_amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_amount);

        switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked == true) {
                    et_payPeople.setEnabled(false);
                    et_payPeople.setClickable(false);
                } else {
                    et_payPeople.setEnabled(true);
                    et_payPeople.setClickable(true);
                }
            }
        });
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.submitButton:
                int people = Integer.parseInt(et_totalPeople.getText().toString());
                //tested with toast here.. didn't work, which means it can't even read from editText
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), people, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                while(people<1 || people>100) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter values 1~100", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    et_totalPeople.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
                    people = Integer.parseInt(et_totalPeople.getText().toString());
                }
                if(switchButton.isChecked()==false) { /*Only certain people pay*/
                    int payer = Integer.parseInt(et_payPeople.getText().toString());
                    while(payer<1 || payer>100) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter values 1~100", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        et_payPeople.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
                        payer = Integer.parseInt(et_payPeople.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
                int amount = Integer.parseInt(et_amount.getText().toString());
                while(amount<1 || amount>10000000) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter values 1~10,000,000", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    et_amount.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
                    amount = Integer.parseInt(et_amount.getText().toString());
                }
                /*now all three values are valid, continue*/
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/restaurant2_lighter"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6effc118"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Everyone pays:   "
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switchButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textOff="NO"
                    android:textOn="YES"
                    android:textSize="15dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6effc118"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter\nthe number\nof people"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_totalPeople"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="ex) 1~99  "
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#4be3cc86"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" people"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6effc118"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_payPeople"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter\nthe number\nof people\nto pay"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_payPeople"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="ex) 1~99  "
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#4be3cc86"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_people"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" people"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6effc118"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter\nthe total\namount"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_amount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="ex) 50000  "
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#4be3cc86"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" won"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6effc118"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/submitButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="submit"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get stuck in an endless loop in your validations as soon as a wrong value is entered. Lets say I enter `101` for `people` then you end up in this loop as soon as you hit the submit button.

```
while(people<1 || people>100) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter values 1~100",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    et_totalPeople.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
    people = Integer.parseInt(et_totalPeople.getText().toString());
}
```

The reason is, that your **while loop runs in the UI thread** of your app and therefore you cannot enter a different value, because for that to be possible the edit text field would need the UI thread for itself.

**To solve this**, do something like this (in pseudo code):

```
onclick() {
    if (people < 1 || people > 100) {
        showToast();
        return;
    }
    if (other-validation-condition == false) {
        showOtherToast();
        return;
    }
    if (yet-another-validation-condition == false) {
        showYetAnotherToast();
        return;
    }
    // now, everything should be valid...
    continueDoingStuffWithValidatedValues();
}
```

Comment: Wow Thanks!! This solved my problem. I don't know much about threads but I will have to look into it. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, in Android development you always have to consider not to do any longer lasting tasks in the main thread (aka UI thread) as this freezes the UI. For longer lasting stuff, there is AsyncTask, Handlers etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), people, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Must be :

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(people), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toast.makeText(Context, int, long). At there, int is resource id.

Comment: I see! Thank you. But my problem is that when I enter the three editTexts and press the 'submit' button, the app stops with the 'submit' button pressed down. It seems as if it's in some sort of loop - just a guess. So, even though I changed that, the toast msg still doesn't appear on my screen. The app just seems stalled. It won't even go back to the previous activity.